# UIButtons stop working after rotation to landscape and then back to portrait

Tags: ios, rotation, uibutton, landscape-portrait

**Overview**: I have a strange error where buttons on the right side of my portrait view don't work after rotating to landscape and then back to portrait again.

**Detail**: Here is the scenario that produces the problem. If I start in portrait, all my buttons work. I rotate to landscape (see code below) and all buttons work. I rotate back to portrait and the buttons on the right 1/4 of the screen do no respond. It's like there is a transparent view that is covering those buttons. What is strange is that if part of the button sticks out to the left of that invisible barrier, I can tap on that part of the button but not on the right part that is "under" the "cover". If I were to rotate to landscape at this point, all the buttons in landscape work. When I rotate back to portrait, that invisible "cover" has moved over to the left another 1/4 to cover roughly 1/2 of the screen. If I rotate again to landscape (all buttons always work in landscape) and then back to portrait, the invisible "cover" has moved over another 1/4 to cover 3/4 of the screen. Eventually, none of my controls respond in portrait.

**Important project information**:

1. This app is universal. The problem only happens in iPad portrait mode. The iPhone version never shows this problem in portrait (or landscape) mode.
2. There are only 3 views: a container view (which is the root), portrait view, and landscape view.
3. This app is ARC and targets 6.1. I have all the correct methods to handle rotation events.

Here is the code for rotating the views:

```
[portrait removeFromSuperview];
[landscape removeFromSuperview];

UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (currentOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) {
    currentOrientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
}
if ((currentOrientation == 0) || (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(currentOrientation))) {
    [[self view] addSubview:portrait];
}
else {   //landscape
    [[self view] addSubview:landscape];
}
```

**What I've tried**:

1. The questions I found that sound remotely similar mentioned checking for memory leaks using Instruments. I tried the zombies and allocations templates and didn't see anything odd (though this is the first I've used Instruments).
2. EDIT: All of this is in the simulator, I haven't tested for this problem on a device yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you queried the subviews at runtime and added a border to each so you can see where they are?

Comment: This has nothing to do with memory leaks, the buttons are probably moving outside their superview's bounds. Give the superview a background color so you can see where it is, and see if that's what's happening.

Comment: You can check two things: 1. The button should be in bounds of its superview. 2. The user interaction of buttons super view should be YES.

Comment: Even easier, set the superview's `clipsToBounds` property to YES.

Comment: **Found the answer!**
The portrait view had autosizing turned on (all springs and struts) whereas the landscape view only had top and left strut on.
I matched portrait's springs and struts to landscape's view and that took care of the problem.
By the way, superview has autoresize subviews checked.

Comment: @LelandKrum - what exactly you did to resolved this problem
could you please showcase any workaround

Answer (score 2):

On your Simulator's menu bar select

Debug - > Color Blended Layers

Then `Command` + `→` rotate it

Then `Command` + `←` rotate it back

There will probably be a view that gets redimensioned weirdly and covers-  maybe partially - your button

Answer (score 0):

i think u r not setting the frame for potrait and landscape properly that means when u rotate it the frame of some other component overlaps with the button frame and so the user interaction gets disabled